How to compute thermal insulation properties of a window
I am planning would like to choose new windows for my house. As I live in a cold region, thermal insulation is important. There are windows made of two glasses with space between them; there are various kinds, which differ mainly in the glass thickness and the distance between the two parts. In order to choose the right window that best fits my budget, it would be good to have a formula that relates the window measurements to its thermal properties. For example, given a window with two 4 mm glasses and 18 mm space between them, how much can I expect to save on heating energy?

Are you sure the window has a vacuum? Or is it an inert gas? If you know the units of the R value that may help: https://www.kingspan.com/gb/en/knowledge-articles/what-are-u-values-r-values-and-lambda-values/#:~:text=A%20product's%20R%2Dvalue%20measures,transfer%20at%20a%20specific%20thickness.

@SolarMike I am not sure it's vacuum. Actually, I think it is plain air.

how did vacuum become part of the discussion here?  you have any idea what would happen if there was a vacuum between the glass of a double pane window?

@ron I don't know why I thought there was vacuum inside. Probably my mistake.

It will depend on many other factors beside thickness and spacing. The manufacturer should be able to give you an R-value, which includes all of these factors.
A very rough indication of savings from double glazing can be calculated here:
https://www.justrite.com.au/how-much-does-insulation-and-double-glazing-help-me-save/ (temperatures in degrees Celsius) or here https://nfrc.org/windows-doors-skylights/window-savings-estimates/

Thanks! I did not find the R-value in their website, but I will try to ask them. Is there a way to compute the savings as a function of the R-value?

There is, but it's complex. Try https://www.e-education.psu.edu/egee102/node/2025 to estimate BTUs, and find out how much your source of heating costs per BTU.

Also this site gives a quick calculation plus a few caveats to watch out for https://www.heatspaceandlight.com/calculate-much-energy-windows-will-save-u-values/ (note that U-value is the inverse of R-value)

Great, thanks for all the information
